# Error while saving a file in Powershell - Access denied

Tags: powershell

I am trying to edit a file and then later on save it using the Save() command in powershell.

I keep getting an error that "Exception calling "Save" with "1" argument(s): "Access to the path '*Path I invoke my PS file from*' is denied." But the folder is not Read-only and as a system admin I have full permissions to that folder as well.

Can anyone let me know if there is anything particularly wrong with what I am doing? Below is my code.

```
$reference.ParentNode.RemoveChild($reference) #Removes the node from csproj               
$pFile.Save($scriptDir) #Saves the file
```

Comment: What is the type of `$pFile`?

Comment: $pFile is a .csproj file